# Kubernetes Daemonset's mounted volumes show no logs/not collecting data

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd, openresty, google-kubernetes-engine

**Context:**

1. We have multiple applications running on k8 cluster. (1.7.12-gke.1 master version)
2. Of which some important application dockers say app1, app2,. are storing some important logs at `/home/services/<application_name>/logs/`
3. We are have Elastic Search - Fluentd - Kibana setup with Daemonset config collecting **STDOUT** and **STDERR** logs from the default example at EFK stack gitrepo.

**Issue:**

I have tried to mount `/home/services` in my daemonset pods and added a custom fluentd config using configMaps. I can see that `/home/services/app1`, `/home/services/app2` folders are getting created but no log files are see in daemonset pods.

I have openresty nginx as one of those app's, which generating logs but I can't see in Kibana.

Please help !!

One related document I found - did not help me much.
* https://medium.com/@joatmon08/application-logging-in-kubernetes-with-fluentd-4556f1573672

Comment: Whew, there's a lot going on in your question. I see you discuss the mount into the DaemonSets, but are the `app1` and `app2` pods _also_ using `hostPath` `volumes` and corresponding `volumeMounts` to surface the logs out of the containers?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - no sir. They are just some locations in app1 and app2 for storing application logs. I did nt do anything to surface the logs out of the container. Please advice.

Comment: Welp, then you're going to need to create volume mounts for the containers, since that's almost the whole point of containerization: to isolate the filesystems of one service from another

Comment: one small doubt, how are /var/log & /var/lib/docker/containers logs are collected ?

Comment: They are not, unless (a) there is a separate, non `DaemonSet`, fluentd configuration (Pods cannot just access any filesystem path they wish, that would gravely compromise the integrity of your cluster) or (b) there is already a `volume` and `volumeMount` setup for `/var/lib` and `/var/log` just as I described